# How to change Json Object

Tags: json.net

Required Format

```
{
    "credentials": {
        "username": "foobar2",
        "password": "Demandware1"
    },
    "profile": {
        "email": "dude@demandware.com",
        "birthday": "2011-05-06",
        "fax": "",
        "first_name": "",
        "gender": "m",
        "job_title": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "phone_business": "",
        "phone_home": "",
        "phone_mobile": "",
        "preferred_locale": "en-US",
        "salutation": "",
        "second_name": "",
        "suffix": "",
        "title": ""
    }
}
```

Current Format

```
{
    "credentials": {
        "username": "aaa",
        "password": "aaa",
        "profile": {
            "email": "admin1@photon.com",
            "birthday": "2011-12-12",
            "fax": "",
            "first_name": "",
            "gender": "",
            "job_title": "",
            "last_name": "",
            "phone_business": "",
            "phone_home": "",
            "phone_mobile": "",
            "Preferred_locale": "a",
            "salutation": "",
            "second_name": "",
            "suffix": "",
            "title": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Current Json Code

```
JObject JsonRegInput = new JObject(
   new JProperty("credentials",
       new JObject(
           new JProperty("username", loginData.username = username),
           new JProperty("password", loginData.password = password),
           new JProperty("profile",
               new JObject(
                   new JProperty("email", RegisterObject.email = email),
                   new JProperty("birthday", RegisterObject.birthday = birthday),
                   new JProperty("fax", RegisterObject.fax = ""),
                   new JProperty("first_name", RegisterObject.first_name = ""),
                   new JProperty("gender", RegisterObject.gender = ""),
                   new JProperty("job_title", RegisterObject.job_title = ""),
                   new JProperty("last_name", RegisterObject.last_name = ""),
                   new JProperty("phone_business", RegisterObject.phone_business = ""),
                   new JProperty("phone_home", RegisterObject.phone_home = ""),
                   new JProperty("phone_mobile", RegisterObject.phone_mobile = ""),
                   new JProperty("Preferred_locale", RegisterObject.preferred_locale = pref_local),
                   new JProperty("salutation", RegisterObject.salutation = ""),
                   new JProperty("second_name", RegisterObject.second_name = ""),
                   new JProperty("suffix", RegisterObject.suffix = ""),
                   new JProperty("title", RegisterObject.title = ""))))));
```

I am giving request for registration along with input. I have written JSON registration format, but I am not getting the required format.  Tell me where I have to change the code.

In the current format I am getting 3 closed brackets at the end. But my requirement is to bring two closed brackets at the end and another one is at the end of password.  Please see my code.

Answer (score 0):

This will work (tested).  Conceptually, you just need to move the "profile" `JProperty` (and its contents) from the "credentials" object to the outer object.  To do this easily, just move two closing parenthesis from the end of the whole statement to just after the "password" `JProperty`.

```
JObject JsonRegInput = new JObject(
    new JProperty("credentials",
        new JObject(
            new JProperty("username", loginData.username = username),
            new JProperty("password", loginData.password = password))),
    new JProperty("profile",
        new JObject(
            new JProperty("email", RegisterObject.email = email),
            new JProperty("birthday", RegisterObject.birthday = birthday),
            new JProperty("fax", RegisterObject.fax = ""),
            new JProperty("first_name", RegisterObject.first_name = ""),
            new JProperty("gender", RegisterObject.gender = ""),
            new JProperty("job_title", RegisterObject.job_title = ""),
            new JProperty("last_name", RegisterObject.last_name = ""),
            new JProperty("phone_business", RegisterObject.phone_business = ""),
            new JProperty("phone_home", RegisterObject.phone_home = ""),
            new JProperty("phone_mobile", RegisterObject.phone_mobile = ""),
            new JProperty("Preferred_locale", RegisterObject.preferred_locale = pref_local),
            new JProperty("salutation", RegisterObject.salutation = ""),
            new JProperty("second_name", RegisterObject.second_name = ""),
            new JProperty("suffix", RegisterObject.suffix = ""),
            new JProperty("title", RegisterObject.title = ""))));
```